# How to set text in Django drop down menu?

Tags: python, django, html, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to set a label for each item of drop down menu? It shows `__str__` outputs from the module instances - items from table.

```
class LanguageDropDownForm(forms.Form):
    languages = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Languages.objects.all().order_by('language_shortcut'))
```

**Models.py:**

```
class Languages(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language_shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    price_per_word = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'SC: {} Lang: {} PPW: {}'.format(self.language_shortcut,self.language,self.price_per_word)
```

Could you give me an advice?

I want for example just `model.language` or `model.name` instead of `__str__` method which is useful for example in `admin`.

Answer (score 0):

Yea. Just use **unicode** instead of what you got there.

```
def __unicode__(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) says, you should inherit the default `ModelChoiceField` for languages field and override `label_from_instance` method:

```
class LanguageModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return 'SC: {} Lang: {} PPW: {}'.format(obj.language_shortcut,
                                                obj.language,
                                                obj.price_per_word)
```

Then in your form you do:

```
class LanguageDropDownForm(forms.Form):
    languages = LanguageModelChoiceField(queryset=Languages.objects.all().order_by('language_shortcut'))
```